# mass decompress gzip files without gz extension

Tags: files, compression, gzip

I have a massive number of files with extensions like `.0_1234` `.0_4213` and `.0_4132` etc. Some of these are `gzip` compressed and some are raw email.  I need to determine which are compressed files, decompress those, and rename all files to a common extension once all compress files are decompressed.  I've found I can use the file command to determine which are compressed, then grep the results and use `sed` to whittle the output down to a list of files, but can't determine how to decompress the seemingly random extensions.  Here's what I have so far

```
file *|grep gzip| sed -e 's/: .*$//g'
```

I'd like to use `xargs` or something to take the list of files provided in output and either rename them to `.gz` so they can be decompressed, or simply decompress them in-line.

Comment: Either move the files that are gzipped to a new/temp directory, or put the output of the list into a file.  If you know the files are just text that is gzipped, then you could just loop through the list and zcat them out to a new file. Not sure how that would work with binary data though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `gzip`, use `zcat` instead which doesn't expect an extension. You can do the whole thing in one go. Just try to `zcat` the file and, if that fails because it isn't compressed, `cat` it instead:

```
for f in *; do 
    ( zcat "$f" || cat "$f" ) > temp && 
    mv temp "$f".ext && 
    rm "$f" 
done
```

The script above will first try to `zcat` the file into `temp` and, if that fails (if the file isn't in gzip format), it will  just `cat` it. This is run in a subshell to capture the output of whichever command runs and redirect it to a temp file (`temp`). Then, the `temp` is renamed to the original file name plus an extension (`.ext` in this example) and the original is deleted.

Comment: Also, you probably want an error check about `"$f".ext` already existing. Or use `mv -i`.

Comment: @don_crissti I know `zcat` uses `gzip` but on my system, at least, I can't get `gzip` to accept files without a `.gz` extension and this gets around that problem. How would I do it in one go?

Comment: @derobert true, although I assumed the OP wouldn't have taht since they want to rename automatically.

Comment: @don_crissti Argh! No I hadn't and I missed the essential detail that you were sending output to stdout. Yes indeed, that's a much better approach. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: A difference between this and calling `gunzip` is that `gunzip` preserves the modification time.

Comment: You should be able to avoid actually copying the uncompressed files with `zcat "$f" > temp || ln -f "$f" temp`  Or maybe `mv` instead of `ln`, to avoid metadata I/O on the inode from incrementing and decrementing the link count?  `mv`'s `rename(2)` still updates the ctime, though.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like

```
for f in ./*
do 
gzip -cdfq "$f" > "${f}".some_ext
done
```

This processes all files (even the uncompressed ones, via `-f`) and writes (via `-c`) the output to *stdout*  using redirection to save the content of each file to its `.some_ext` counterpart. You could then remove the originals e.g. with `bash`

```
shopt extglob
rm -f ./!(*.some_ext)
```

or `zsh`

```
setopt extendedglob
rm -f ./^*some_ext
```

You could even save the resulting files to another dir (this time assuming you want to remove the original extension) e.g.

```
for f in *
do 
gzip -cdfq -- "$f" > /some/place/else/"${f%.*}".some_ext
done
```

and then remove everything in the current dir...

Comment: Like Terdon's answer, this doesn't avoid copying the uncompressed files.  But if you don't care about that, gzip's `-f` option to pass through non-gzipped data unchanged is the way to go, so +1.

Answer (score 3):

This will present a list of all files compressed with gzip:

```
file /path/to/files | grep ': gzip compressed data' | cut -d: -f1
```

To tack a `.gz` extension on any gzipped files, this ugly hack might do:

```
for file in ./*; do
    if gzip -l "$file" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        case "$file" in
          *.gz) :;; # The file already has the extension corresponding to its format
          *) mv "$file" "${file}.gz";;
        esac
        # Uncomment the following line to decompress them at the same time
        # gunzip "${file}.gz"
    fi
done
```